# How to console.log the innerText from elements that were removed?

Tags: javascript, html

In my `updateCartTotal()` function I want to `console.log` the elements that were removed from my shopping cart.

Each time I press the remove button, I want it to print out the `item`, and `price`. However, whenever I do it it returns undefined. And in some instances it only recognizes 1 item only. I don't think there is a problem with my JavaScript code rather it may be my HTML

```
const updateCartTotal = () => {
    var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
    var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')

    for(var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++){
        var cartRow = cartRows[i];
        var itemElement= cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-item')[0].innerHTML
        var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0].innerHTML
        var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]

        var item = itemElement.innerText
        var price = priceElement.innerText
        // var quantity = quantityElement.value
        console.log(item, price)
    }
}
```

```
<section class="container shopping-cart">
    <div class="title">Cart</div>
    <div class="cart-row">
        <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
        <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
        <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>
    </div>
    <div class="cart-items">
        <div class="cart-row">
            <div class="cart-item">
                <span class="cart-item-title">Item 1</span>
            </div>
            <span class="cart-price ">$14.99</span>
            <div class="cart-quantity-input">
                <input type="number" value="1">
                <button class="btn btn-danger ml-5" type="button">REMOVE</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cart-row">
            <div class="cart-item">
                <span class="cart-item-title ">Item 2</span>
            </div>
            <span class="cart-price">$79.99</span>
            <div class="cart-quantity-input">
                <input type="number" value="2">
                <button class="btn btn-danger ml-5" type="button">REMOVE</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You already set the variable to `.innerHTML`, you don't need to use `.innerText` as well.

Comment: May I introduce you to [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), so that you don't need to use `[0]` on every row?

Answer (score 1):

`item` and `price` will not be elements. They are strings representing the innerHTML of the elements.
To get the item name, simply use `cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title')[0].innerHTML`.
To get the price, use `cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0].innerHTML`.

Do NOT use innerText, as this will cause an error since `item` and `price` are already strings.

```js
const updateCartTotal = () => {
  var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
  var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
  
  for (var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++) {
    var cartRow = cartRows[i];
    var item = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-item-title')[0].innerHTML
    var price = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0].innerHTML
    var quantity = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]
    
    console.log(" Item: " + item + "\n" +
                "Price: " + price)
  }
}
updateCartTotal();
```

```html
<section class="container shopping-cart">
  <div class="title">Cart</div>
  <div class="cart-row">
    <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
    <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
    <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>
  </div>
  <div class="cart-items">
    <div class="cart-row">
      <div class="cart-item">
        <span class="cart-item-title">Item 1</span>
      </div>
      <span class="cart-price ">$14.99</span>
      <div class="cart-quantity-input">
        <input type="number" value="1">
        <button class="btn btn-danger ml-5" type="button">REMOVE</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cart-row">
      <div class="cart-item">
        <span class="cart-item-title">Item 2</span>
      </div>
      <span class="cart-price">$79.99</span>
      <div class="cart-quantity-input">
        <input type="number" value="2">
        <button class="btn btn-danger ml-5" type="button">REMOVE</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: For button `$(element)[0].innerHTML`, to see options just `console.log($(element))`.

Answer (score 0):

I could not see how your current code was console logging the values based on the button click. So I created the function removeItem() that acheives the functionality you want. Use this solution to add the functionality to your code.

See the Code Pen for a solution.

https://codepen.io/ianroskow/pen/WNeagXQ

On the onclick of the remove button, I pass the context and then traverse the dom to console log the desired values.

I used closest to find the parent node, and query selector to find the child.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

```js
 const updateCartTotal = () => {

            var cartItemContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('cart-items')[0]
            var cartRows = cartItemContainer.getElementsByClassName('cart-row')
            for(var i = 0; i < cartRows.length; i++){
                var cartRow = cartRows[i];
                var itemElement= cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-item')[0].innerHTML
                var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0].innerHTML
                var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-quantity-input')[0]

                var item = itemElement.innerText
                var price = priceElement.innerText
                // var quantity = quantityElement.value
                console.log(item, price)
            }

        }
 
 function removeItem(element){
   const cartRow = element.closest(".cart-row");
   console.log(cartRow.querySelector(".cart-item-title").innerHTML);
   console.log(cartRow.querySelector(".cart-price").innerHTML);
   cartRow.parentNode.removeChild(cartRow);
 }
```

```html
    <section class="container shopping-cart">
            <div class="title">Cart</div>
            <div class="cart-row">
                <span class="cart-item cart-header cart-column">ITEM</span>
                <span class="cart-price cart-header cart-column">PRICE</span>
                <span class="cart-quantity cart-header cart-column">QUANTITY</span>
            </div>
            <div class="cart-items">
                <div class="cart-row">
                    <div class="cart-item">
                        <span class="cart-item-title">Item 1</span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="cart-price ">$14.99</span>
                    <div class="cart-quantity-input">
                        <input type="number" value="1">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger ml-5" onclick="removeItem(this)"  type="button">REMOVE</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="cart-row">
                    <div class="cart-item">
                        <span class="cart-item-title ">Item 2</span>
                    </div>
                    <span class="cart-price">$79.99</span>
                    <div class="cart-quantity-input">
                        <input type="number" value="2">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger ml-5" onclick="removeItem(this)" type="button">REMOVE</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Sorry I should've provided a little more additonal code, but the function i used to remove my buttons was  `const removeCartItems = () => {
     const buttonClicked = event.target;
    buttonClicked.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
     updateCartTotal()
}`

Comment: The problem with your approach is you are removing the item before you are console logging it. That is why sometimes it only console logs one item. Change your code to log the item and price before you remove it. Like I recommended in the removeItem function.